# The Tic Tac Toe game does not show the winner at the right time

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

my code is tic tac toe and i have problem with show winner.
i get winner but not when X or O in correct direction.
and show winner after click on button.

code :

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;

public class TicTocToe extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7730552764304282715L;
    private static final Font BT_FONT = new Font("Segoe UI", 0, 30);
    private static final Font LB_FONT = new Font("Consolas", 0, 20);

    private JButton[][] board;
    private JLabel statusBar;
    private JPanel centerPanel, southPanel;
    private int turn = 0, count = 0;
    private String name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new TicTocToe().setVisible(true));

    }

    public TicTocToe() {

        super("Tic Toc Toe");

        try {

            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
            initUI();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    private void initUI() {

        initCenterPanel();
        initSouthPanel();

        add(centerPanel);
        add(southPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private void initCenterPanel() {

        centerPanel = new JPanel();

        board = new JButton[3][3];

        for (int i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                board[i][j] = new JButton("-");
                board[i][j].setFont(BT_FONT);
                board[i][j].setFocusPainted(false);
                board[i][j].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
                board[i][j].addActionListener(this);

                centerPanel.add(board[i][j]);

            }

        }

    }

    private void initSouthPanel() {

        southPanel = new JPanel();
        southPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        statusBar = new JLabel();
        statusBar.setFont(LB_FONT);
        statusBar.setText("Click On Button To Start");
        statusBar.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        statusBar.setBorder(new EtchedBorder());

        southPanel.add(statusBar);
    }

    private void play(JButton button) {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                if (button.equals(board[i][j])) {

                    count++;

                    if (turn < 1) {

                        statusBar.setText("Player " + "O" + " Turn");
                        button.setText("X");
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        turn++;

                    } else {

                        statusBar.setText("Player " + "X" + " Turn");
                        button.setText("O");
                        button.setEnabled(false);
                        turn--;

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    private String getPlayerName() {
        return (turn < 1) ? "X" : "O";

    }

    private boolean findWinner() {

        name = getPlayerName();

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            if (board[i][0].getText().equals(name) && board[i][1].getText().equals(name)
                    && board[i][2].getText().equals(name))

                return true;

            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {

                if (board[0][j].getText().equals(name) && board[1][j].getText().equals(name)
                        && board[2][j].getText().equals(name))

                    return true;

                if (board[0][0].getText().equals(name) && board[1][1].getText().equals(name)
                        && board[2][2].getText().equals(name))

                    return true;

                if (board[0][2].getText().equals(name) && board[1][1].getText().equals(name)
                        && board[2][0].getText().equals(name))

                    return true;

            }

        }

        return false;

    }

    private void showWinner() {

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {

                if (findWinner()) {

                    if (getPlayerName().equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {

                        statusBar.setText("Winner is Player X");
                        board[i][j].removeActionListener(this);
                    }

                    else if (getPlayerName().equalsIgnoreCase("o")) {

                        statusBar.setText("Winner is Player O");
                        board[i][j].removeActionListener(this);

                    }

                } else if (!findWinner() && count == 9) {

                    statusBar.setText("It was a draw, no wone.");
                    board[i][j].removeActionListener(this);

                }

            }
        }

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

        JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();

        play(button);
        showWinner();

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 320);

    }

    public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
        return getPreferredSize();

    }

}
```

[image]

in this image Winner is X but wait for Player O

[image]

and after click on other button show Winner.
i need show winner when X or O in correct Direction
and no wait for click on other button

Answer (score 2):

I think I see it.

When a button is pressed, you do stuff in this order:

1. change the status bar to say it's the next player's turn
2. set the relevant button text to show the player who just picked that button
3. disable the button
4. change the turn value to reflect the next player
5. check for a winner, based on the current player's name *but you have already changed this to the next player, not the player who just made the move*.

When X makes a winning move, the current player name is changed to O before the game checks for a winner, so it checks to see if O has won.  You need to reorder stuff:

1. change the button text
2. disable the button
3. check for a winner based on the current player name, end the game if the current player has won or if there is a draw
4. if the game is still going, now is the time to change the turn value and update the status bar to show that it's the next player's turn.